# Mongoose + MongoDB - Cast to ObjectID failed for value after try save with POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save an object that references other 2 objects in mongoDB, but I'm not getting it. Whenever I try, I get this message.

For this, this using POSTMAN to test the API that I am creating.

```
{
    "message": "Order validation failed: payments.0.credit_card.card: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ number: '4898308633754712',\n  holder_name: 'Test test',\n  exp_month: 1,\n  exp_year: 2022,\n  cvv: '1234' }\" at path \"credit_card.card\", customer: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ name: 'Test Test', email: 'test@gmail.com' }\" at path \"customer\""
}
```

The json object I'm trying to save in mongoDB:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "name": "Plano s",
    "amount": 12345,
    "description": "Descrição do Plano Sanarflix",
    "quantity": 1
  }],
  "customer": {
    "name": "Test Test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  "payments": [{
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "credit_card": {
        "installments":1,
        "capture": true,
      "card": {
        "number": "4898308633754712",
        "holder_name": "Test Test",
        "exp_month": 1,
        "exp_year": 2022,
        "cvv": "1234"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

This is the model order I defined:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Model for order
const schema = new Schema({
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer',
        required: function(){
            return this.customer_id;
        }        
    },
    items: [{
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    payments: [{
        payment_method: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        credit_card: {
            installments: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            },
            capture: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            card: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Card'
            }  
        },
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', schema);
```

What is wrong with it? Because when I import the same json to MongoDB with Studio3 Mongo Manager, I can save it and see the object in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

*an object that references other 2 objects*, yes, `ObjectId` does references, yet you're passing the whole objects.

Three options:

- pass the `id` of `customer` and `card` objects (if they exist already)
- insert these new data in their respective collections *then* insert your order using the created IDs (likely *the* solution)
- rewrite your schema to have only the `Order` collection that would hold everything (not really great).

Also, having card numbers transiting through your server is **really dangerous** (legally speaking), especially if you're to store them... check out how the payment service you're implementing handles transactions: on any decent service the server never sees banking data, discharging your company of any liability.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my question.

So I am aware that the card data should not be saved in the bank or traffic on the server.

How could I do this?

"rewrite your schema to have only the Order collection that would hold everything (not really great)."

Comment: Well you would define the `Order` schema with `card` being an object defined with the proper fields (what you must currently have as a `Card` schema). Same for the customer. But this is not a great solution: it would need you to aggregate data each time you want to extract customer data (like history of orders, for instance). IMHO you should keep these separated, and really insert an `ObjectId` that references the customer. (However you may want to freeze some customer data in `Order`, such as the name, delivery/billing address...)